# How do I change my iframe source on button click in HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

I am new to HTML and have been reverse engineering code to suit my own needs for developing an updated internal website for my work.

Currently I have my code linking to different .htm pages that simulate being on the same page. Obviously this is entirely too tedious to change if I need to add or change documents.

I know that I can change the source for an iframe, but every solution I have seen doesn't work for me. I'm so inexperienced I don't even know where to start. I've tried the onclick function, but it just breaks my buttons and does nothing beyond that.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!---Version: 2.x FOUNDATION--->
<html>
<head>
 <title align="center">MainPage</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown {
    top: 7px;
    position: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    left: -100%;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change background on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-top: 59px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}
iframe {
    display: block;
    border-style:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!---Creates a Navbar at the top of the screen. Will scroll with site if content of the "Main" section is long enough.--->
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="mainPage.htm"> <p align="center" style="font-size:100%;"><b>Main Page</b></p></a> <!---Creates a "button" that links to the main page.--->
    <div class="dropdown"> <!---The start of the buttons and drop down menus inside the Navbar.--->
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">On Air</a>
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="button1.htm">Example1</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><!---Creates a submenu inside of the parent menu.--->
        <a class= "test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Weather<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex"-1" href="submenuButton1.htm">Example 2</a><li>

<div class="main"> <!---Creates the Main section of the page that the navabar sits over.--->
<p align="center">Welcome to the new and improved sampleURL.</p>

<!---Creates an iframe that displays the sampleURL.--->
<p align="center"><iframe name="mainframe" width="100%" height="770" src="sampleURL.htm?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="transparent"></iframe></p>


</div>

 </a>
 
 <script><!---A script that allows the submenu functions to work properly.--->
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a custom class to each  tag that changes the iframe like this:

```
<a class="iframe-change" tabindex"-1" href="submenuButton1.htm">Example 2</a>
```

Now, catch the click event with this javascript script:

```
$(".iframe-change").on("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the <a> event
 $("[name=mainframe]").attr("src", $(this).attr("href")); // Changes the iframe "src" property to the url setted in the clicked <a>
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly. I should have known javascript would be the solution.